# problem in passing values between classes in flutter

Tags: android, flutter

I am still training on flutter so no full knowledge yet.

Now I am trying to receive an array of data from a web server on the app in form of list I created the API and it worked the idea now is that I have a list of contacts and each contact received its data and viewing it in middle of this data is the id of the contact I want when I click on a contact its id sent to another class which is the details of the contact page so the in the details page it sends the id to the API again to receive a full data about the contact but when I do that it says cannot receive a null value can anybody help
the first-page code and the second page and the error in the emulator[no such method error the getter length was called on null receiver: null tried calling: lenght](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ViOc5.png)

```dart
class topfreelancers extends StatefulWidget {
@override
_topfreelancers createState() => _topfreelancers();
}

class _topfreelancers extends State<topfreelancers> {
List data = [];


@override
void initState() {
fetchData();
super.initState();
}

void fetchData() async {
final response = await http.get('http://10.0.2.2/phpapi/getfreelancers.php');

if (response.statusCode == 200) {
setState(() {
data = json.decode(response.body);
});
}
}
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return
Column(
children: <Widget>[
Row(children: <Widget>[
SizedBox(width:15),
Text(
'Weekly Top 10 Freelancers',
textAlign: TextAlign.left,
overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.normal ,fontSize: 18),
)
],)
,SizedBox(height: 20),
Container(
height:200,
width:MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
child:ListView.builder(
physics: BouncingScrollPhysics(),
scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
itemCount: data.length,
itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) =>
Container(
child:
Row(children: <Widget>[
SizedBox(width:10),
Column(
children: <Widget>[
Stack(
children: <Widget>[
Column(children: <Widget>[
Stack(
children: <Widget>[
SizedBox(height:10),
CircleAvatar(
backgroundImage:
NetworkImage(data[index]['image']),
child:FlatButton(
color: Colors.transparent,
splashColor: Colors.transparent,
onPressed: (){
Navigator.push(
context,
MaterialPageRoute(
builder: (context) => information(id:data[index]['id'])
));
}
) ,
radius: 60,
),
],
),
Row(
children: <Widget>[
SizedBox(width:5),
Container(
width: 40,
height: 20,
decoration: BoxDecoration(
color: const Color(0xffffffff),
borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
boxShadow:[BoxShadow(offset: const Offset(0,3), blurRadius: 6,color: const Color(0xff000000).withOpacity(0.16),)],
),
child:Row(children:<Widget>[
SizedBox(width:2),
Icon(Icons.star,color:Colors.yellow,size:20),
SizedBox(width:1),
Text(
data[index]['id'],
textAlign: TextAlign.center,
style: TextStyle(
fontFamily: 'SF Display',
fontSize: 11,
color: Color(0xff202020),
),
)],),
)
],
)
],)
],
),
SizedBox(height:5),
Text(
data[index]['name'],
textAlign: TextAlign.center,
overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,fontSize: 15),
),
SizedBox(height:5),
Text(
data[index]['category'],
textAlign: TextAlign.center,
overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.normal,fontSize: 12),
)
],
)
],)
)
),
),
Row(
children: <Widget>[
SizedBox(width:700),
GestureDetector(onTap: (){
null;
},
child:
const Text(
'see more',
textAlign: TextAlign.center,
style: TextStyle(
fontFamily: 'SF Display',
fontSize: 16,
color: Color(0xff2a3377),
decoration: TextDecoration.underline,
),
),
)
],
)
]
);

}
}
```

the second page

```dart
class ApiProvider {

  final String key =information().id;


  Future<Post> fetchPost() async {



    final response = await http.post("https://10.0.2.2/phpapi/select.php", body:{"key": key});


    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      return  Post.fromJson(json.decode(response.body));
    } else {
      throw Exception('Failed to load post');
    }
  }
}



class Post{
  final  userid;
  final  username;
  final  userphone;
  Post({this.userid,this.username,this.userphone});
  factory Post.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json){
    return Post(
      userid: json['id'],
      username: json['name'],
      userphone: json['phone'],
    );
  }
}


class information extends StatefulWidget {
  String id;
  information({this.id});


  @override
  _data createState() => _data();
}

class _data extends State<information> {

  final Future<Post> post = ApiProvider().fetchPost();
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(),
        body:
        Center(
            child: FutureBuilder<Post>(
                future: post,
                builder: (context, snapshot){
                  if (snapshot.hasData){
                    return
                      Column(
                        children: <Widget>[
                          SizedBox(height:80),
                          SizedBox(height:80),
                          SizedBox(height:80),
                          Text(snapshot.data.userid),
                          Text(snapshot.data.username),
                          Text(snapshot.data.userphone)
                        ],
                      );
                  }else if (snapshot.hasError){
                    return Text("${snapshot.error}");
                  }
                  return CircularProgressIndicator();
                }
            )
        )
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Could you post the full error output of the debug console

Comment: Most likely your call of length here is causing the error  itemCount: data.length. You could fix it with some conditional checking. Something like this might work: itemCount: data?.length ?? 0

Comment: still the same error the problem is that no value is transferred from the first class to the second so there is no search key sent to the the API

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `initState` and set parameter with `fetchPost(widget.id)` 
code snippet

```
Future<Post> fetchPost(String key) async {
    final response = await http
        .post("https://10.0.2.2/phpapi/select.php", body: {"key": key});
... 
class _data extends State<information> {
  Future<Post> post;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    post = ApiProvider().fetchPost(widget.id);
  }
```

full code snippet

```
class ApiProvider {
  //final String key = information().id;

  Future<Post> fetchPost(String key) async {
    final response = await http
        .post("https://10.0.2.2/phpapi/select.php", body: {"key": key});

    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      return Post.fromJson(json.decode(response.body));
    } else {
      throw Exception('Failed to load post');
    }
  }
}

class information extends StatefulWidget {
  String id;
  information({this.id});

  @override
  _data createState() => _data();
}

class _data extends State<information> {
  Future<Post> post;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    post = ApiProvider().fetchPost(widget.id);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(),
        body: Center(
            child: FutureBuilder<Post>(
                future: post,
                builder: (context, snapshot) {
                  if (snapshot.hasData) {
                    return Column(
                      children: <Widget>[
                        SizedBox(height: 80),
                        SizedBox(height: 80),
                        SizedBox(height: 80),
                        Text(snapshot.data.userid),
                        Text(snapshot.data.username),
                        Text(snapshot.data.userphone)
                      ],
                    );
                  } else if (snapshot.hasError) {
                    return Text("${snapshot.error}");
                  }
                  return CircularProgressIndicator();
                })));
  }
}
```

Comment: Glad to help. please mark this as answer if it helps you. thanks.